# C++14 stack allocated shared pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a Pre C++11/14 code base that I'm updating.

The code almost elusively uses stack allocation, and then passes those pointers around, for example:

```
{
  KlassX x;
  KlassY y;

  y.doThings( &x );  //Holds the pointer to KlassX for later use

  return mainLoop(); //Doesn't return until the program finishes
}
```

In this case, KlassY doesn't know anything about the allocation of memory for *KlassX.  In this specific application its safe, but its not "Safe code" because if KlassY were used in a different way, it doesn't use shared_ptr to track de-allocation on a pointer its holding.

I'd rather implement KlassY to use a shared_ptr, without changing the program over to heap allocation.  Is there a safe way I can keep using the stack allocation scheme, but have KlassY use a shared_ptr for KlassX?

I apologize if this is a duplicate, I did a fair amount of googling and couldn't find an answer for this question.

Comment: What ever gave you the idea that this is not safe code? As long as `KlassY` has no illusions of ownership of the pointer to `KlassX` and is null pointer safe, this is entirely safe code.

Comment: As I stated, within this specific contexts of usage, it is safe.  However if I want to some day pick up KlassY, and drop it into an entirely different program environment, it wouldn't be safe anymore.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no reason to use `shared_ptr` here. You're not sharing ownership! `doThings()` doesn't take ownership of `&x` (it cannot possibly do that), it's just observing it. There's nothing wrong with passing around raw, observing pointers. If you want to emphasize that in C++11, you can simply define:

```
template <class T>
using observer_ptr = T*;
```

(which is actually a real class type in [library funtamentals TS v2](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr), but basically just a very thin wrapper around a raw pointer) and pass that instead. This isn't conceptually or semantically different from a raw pointer, we're making it even more clear to all parties that there is **no ownership** going on here. Just observation semantics.

Besides, what would sharing ownership of a stack object mean?

Comment: If in the future I want to pick up KlassY, and drop it into an entirely different implementation, that it would safely handle that situation.  I like you're idea of creating the thin wrapper to get my intensions across.  Thank you.

Comment: Using unique pointers.  What if I want a unique vector of pointers allocated on the stack.  I have been told this makes no sense as smart pointers are used for memory management.  Should i use a set or unique vector of pointer instead?

Answer (score -1):

Almost anything is possible

```
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
struct NonDeleter {
    void operator()(T* t) {}
};

struct KlassX {};

class KlassY {
    std::shared_ptr<KlassX> klassx_;
public:
    KlassY() : klassx_(nullptr) {}
    void doThings(std::shared_ptr<KlassX> klassX) {
        klassx_ = klassX;
    }
};

int mainLoop() { return 0; }

int main() {
    KlassX x;
    KlassY y;

    std::shared_ptr<KlassX> xptr(&x, NonDeleter<KlassX>());
    y.doThings(xptr);

    return mainLoop();
}
```

http://ideone.com/BXkYYq

But not everything is desirable. The purpose of `shared_ptr` is to convey ownership, and here we are perverting that meaning. Further, under the hood, shared_ptr may be implemented under the hood to dynamically allocate the shared data block.

Of course, you're also burdening your application with the cost of adding and subtracting to the ref count every time you pass this shared pointer around.

That might be a slight source of justification, however, for doing this:

```
KlassX x;
KlassY y;

std::shared_ptr<KlassX> xptr(&x, NonDeleter<KlassX>());
y.doThings(xptr);

int r = mainLoop();

// make sure we didn't leak references
assert(xptr.use_count() == 1);

return r;
```

I think this justification is pretty tenuous, though.

Unless you are planning to be a reference-count-checker and you want your functions to, in future, support shared dynamic allocation handling, you should stick with raw pointers or leverage the C++17s proposed [observer ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr) concept which explicitly indicates non-ownership. [see the [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3840.pdf) for a possible implementation]

Answer (score -1):

You could design `KlassY::doThings` so that it accepts a `std::shared_ptr`.
Then you can use the *aliasing constructor* of `std::shared_ptr` (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) for further details) to work around the fact that **you don't need actually a shared pointer in your example code**.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>

void f(std::shared_ptr<int> ptr) {
    std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    int x = 42;
    std::shared_ptr<int> fake{};
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptr{fake, &x};
    f(ptr);
}
```

As long as you can ensure that the lifetime of `x` is at least equal to the one of `y`, you won't have any problem.

Note that this way you are not allocating space for your `int` and you are passing around a stack allocated one, that is what you were asking for and allows smooth migration towards a new architecture if needed.

Comment: I'm somewhat fine with using the aliasing constructor to work around broken interfaces. But intentionally designing a broken interface?

Comment: @T.C. Do you work with the OP and knows what's the real problem? I don't, so I'm trying to figure out what can help him and I tried to stay true to the question. He is asking such an interface, that's the way to go. I have not to agree with what he's doing.